# Experimental Verification of Van der Waals parameters?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, van-der-waals-behavior

I am currently trying to find an academic paper that experimentally verifies the a and b values of Van der Waals forces for carbon dioxide. I can't seem to find this, and am wondering if I am missing something. Could somebody either give me a reason this is so hard to find, or link me a paper I have proven myself incapable of finding?

If this is impossible, is there a paper that empirically computes the answer?

Comment: It is the best tested by verification of critical parameters, which are directly linked to the vdW a,b parameters. Measuring V=f(p,n,T) or similar would give different parameters,  depending on the used p,T  region and deviation of the real gas from vdW model.

Comment: There are a dozen of far better gas equations. Nobody uses vdW, because if you actually need the improved accuracy over the ideal gas equation, you'd have to either experimentally determine good parameters for the p,V range you are interested in, or derive them from one of the other equations (which have up to ten parameters!). The first is a lot of work, the second is pointless, because you can directly use the more accurate equation.